# Oksendal SDE book mistake?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am reading through Oksendals SDEs. I think there may be a mistake in question 5.18b and I can not find an errata so I was looking for some confirmation. The problem concerns the following SDE

$\mathrm{d}X_t = \kappa (\alpha - \log X_t)X_t\mathrm{d}t + \sigma X_t \mathrm{d}B_t,\;\;\;X_0 = x>0 $

There is a hint to change variables to $Y_t = \log X_t$. This gives the following SDE for $Y_t$

$\mathrm{d}Y_t = \kappa(\alpha - Y_t)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma \mathrm{d}B_t - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \mathrm{d}t$

This can be solved using an integrating factor

$Y_t = Y_0 e^{-\kappa t}+(\alpha-\frac{1}{2\kappa}\sigma^2)(1-e^{-\kappa t})+\sigma e^{-\kappa t}\int_0^{t}e^{\kappa s}\mathrm{d}B_s$

Okay now part b wants us compute $E[X_t]$. For a fixed time all the terms in $Y_t$ but the  last one are constants hence

$E[X_t] = E[\exp(Y_t)]\\
 = \exp(e^{-\kappa t }\ln x + (\alpha-\frac{1}{2\kappa}\sigma^2)(1-e^{-\kappa t}))E[\exp(\sigma e^{-\kappa t}\int_0^{t}e^{\kappa s}\mathrm{d}B_s)]$

Okay now it seems to me that the random variable $\sigma e^{-\kappa t}\int_0^{t}e^{\kappa s}\mathrm{d}B_s$ is normally distributed, since it is the limit of a sum of normally distributed random variables, I haven't rigorously proven this to myself but I do not think there is any subtlety that would mess things up. Clearly it must have mean $0$, and the variance can be computed using Ito isometry. If I do that I get that the variance is

$E[(\sigma e^{-\kappa t}\int_0^{t}e^{\kappa s}\mathrm{d}B_s)^2]=\frac{\sigma^2(1-e^{-2\kappa t})}{2\kappa}$

Hence now the expectation term above becomes a moment generating function of a Gaussian with a known mean and variance, evaluated at $1$. It seems to me that this will give us

$E[X_t] = \exp(e^{-\kappa t }\ln x + (\alpha-\frac{1}{2\kappa}\sigma^2)(1-e^{-\kappa t}))\exp(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2(1-e^{-2\kappa t})}{2\kappa})\\
= \exp(e^{-\kappa t }\ln x + (\alpha-\frac{1}{2\kappa}\sigma^2)(1-e^{-\kappa t})+ \frac{\sigma^2(1-e^{-2\kappa t})}{4\kappa})$

The problem is that Oksendal wants us to prove that 
$E[X_t] = \exp(e^{-\kappa t }\ln x + (\alpha-\frac{1}{2\kappa}\sigma^2)(1-e^{-\kappa t})+ \frac{\sigma^2(1-e^{-2\kappa t})}{2\kappa})$

Is there a mistake in his answer or did I make a mistake somewhere?

I did some simulations and they seemed to be in pretty strong agreement with my result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. The stochastic Itô integral is a Gaussian random variable with mean zero, since the integrand is an $L_a^2([0,T]\times \Omega)$ process (in fact, deterministic)

The mean is 0, (it is a martingale) and the variance (second moment), by Itô's isometry, is

$$\sigma^2 e^{-2\kappa t} E\left[\int_0^t e^{-2\kappa s}ds\right] = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\kappa} \left( 1- e^{-2\kappa t}\right).$$

Then the exponential is a $log$-normal and so on.

I do not have the book with me right now but if you copied everything correctly it should be a typo. It is not a major error though.

Comment: No it's not major. There are no major mistakes in this book as far as I can tell; which is why I really wanted confirmation that this wasn't right. The first book I learned stochastics from was Grigoriu.. holy moly there's mistakes on top of mistakes in that. Anyway thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: No problem. In any case, there are around six editions of this book. You can also check if you find the same mistake in the latest edition, just to make sure.

Comment: I have the 6th ;^)

Comment: Actually I got curious, what are you saying are is a sufficient condition for an Ito integral to be Gaussian? I can clearly see how it's true for a deterministic integrand that is square integrable. I know what $L^2$ is, I don't know what $L^2_a$ is. I guess I would ask what an example of a non-deterministic integrand that would also work is; and for what reason $B_t$ fails your condition since $\int B_t \mathrm{d}B_t$ is not Gaussian.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was the standard notation from Øksendal. For me $L_a^2([0,T]\times\Omega)$ means the square-integrable processes that are adapted (hence "a") to the filtration generated by $B_t,t\in [0,T]$, otherwise the Itô integral is not well-defined (other integrals for non-adapted integrands can be used). So, for an Itô integral to make sense first, the intengrand must be square-integrable but also adapted! Example: the Brownian bridge is not adapted, or for example $B_T$ is not adapted, $B_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable but not $\mathcal{F}_t$, $s< T$ measurable.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But $Y_t = \int_0^t B_s dB_s = B_t^2/2 - t/2$ isn't Gaussian, and $B_t$ is clearly adapted so I think that this isn't a strong enough condition to guarantee the resulting integral is a Gaussian RV.

Comment: Probably any integral that is linear in $B_t$ would work?

Comment: Itô integrals need not be Gaussian no. Itô processes are Gaussian though.

Comment: I agree. I was just clarifying what you meant here "The stochastic Itô integral is a Gaussian random variable with mean zero, since the integrand is an L2a([0,T]×Ω) process (in fact, deterministic)"

Comment: Ah well I was referring to "the stochastic Itô integral" from you question :) which has deterministic integrand and hence adapted and hence it is Gaussian. But yes, it must be clear.

Comment: Okay I guess what you are saying is (deterministic integrand --> adapted --> integral well defined) and also (deterministic integrand --> gaussian rv result). I tought what you were saying was (deterministic integrand --> adapted --> gaussian rv result) which didnt make sense to me because (adapted --> gaussian rv result) isnt true.